# Why can't I play online after changing my profile name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Yesterday, I changed my profile name. Now I can't play online anymore.

When I log on, it says

> Account not authenticated with *minecraft.net*

and

> Non-Valid Username.

Comment: Are you sure it can only be the change in username? You haven't changed anything else?

Comment: Did you have internet problems while starting the game or while trying to connect to the server? Even just a slow connection? Or are you maybe playing in a very old version of Minecraft?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try logging out and logging back in on the Minecraft Launcher? Many times I ran into this problem and this solved the problem.